# Pytest-xdist - how can I know which worker collected which items (tests)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-xdist

In pytest I use fixture `request` in order to get collected itmes by using `request.session.items`, which gives me function items.

I'm running pytest using `xdist` with worker number > 1 and I want to know, before the first test runs, which worker will run which items.

It seems that each worker collects all tests in `request.session.items` so it's not a per-worker information and I can't use it.

How can I get this info ?